# Find Galois group for normal closure - can't find error

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}}$. It's minimal polynomial is $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 - 1$. Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$. Other roots of $f(x)$ are $-\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}}$ (because $f(x)$ has only even powers). Then after deviding $f(x)$ by $g(x) = (x - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}})(x + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}}) = x^2 - (2 + \sqrt{5})$, we get $h(x) = x^2 - (2 - \sqrt{5})$ and by quadratic formula, we find its roots to be $\sqrt{\sqrt{5} - 2}\imath$ and $-\sqrt{\sqrt{5} - 2}\imath$. So $h(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, hence it is minimal polynomial of $\beta = \sqrt{\sqrt{5} - 2}\imath$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 2$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 4.2 = 8$. (I think now will come an error) Possible $\mathbb{Q}$-automoprhisms are such that $\alpha \mapsto \pm \alpha, \beta \mapsto \pm \beta$, but that gives only $4$ possible $\mathbb{Q}$-automoprhisms, but certain theorem says this:

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the group of automorphisms of a field $K$ and let $K_0$ be the fixed field of $G$. Then $[K:K_0] = |G|$.

If we take $G$ the whole group (which would have $4$ elements by what I said), $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta), K_0 = \mathbb{Q}$, we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 8 \neq 4 = |G|$.

I have no idea where I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots are $\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt5}$ and $\pm i\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}$. But there
are Galois automorphisms taking $\sqrt{2+\sqrt5}$ to $i\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}$.

Comment: Oh, they can be like that? Thanks, gonna try to check if they are really automorphisms (not that I don't believe you, but it's good for me to see it). Thanks again! Anyway, the rest is fine?

Comment: @PanMiroslav There must be: the Galois group acts transitively on the zeros of $f$.